# A spring boot app deployed to cloud run won't run due to cloud sql instance configuration

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-run

I have a small application written in Springboot for the purpose of learning Cloud SQL and Cloud run. I followed the connect to [cloud run guide](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-run#java_1). I set up a cloud SQL instance configuring it with a private IP address, and I created a Serverless VPC Access connector which I used in my cloud run instance. In my application properties file, I added the [JDBC URL](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory/blob/main/docs/jdbc-mysql.md) path with the necessary fields, but when I submit my build, the application breaks. What could I have done wrong?

The logs don't say much but here is a snapshot of the error message

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]
```

My application.properties file

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql:///<db-name>?\
cloudSqlInstance=<connection name>&\
socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory&\
user=<username>&\
password=<password>&\
ipTypes=PRIVATE
```

My pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.tbm5k</groupId>
    <artifactId>cloud-sql-connection-test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>cloud-sql-connection-test</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.sql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-socket-factory-connector-j-8</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>-->
<!--            <scope>runtime</scope>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

My cloudbuild.yaml file

```
steps:
  # Build the container image
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args: ['build', '-t', 'gcr.io/project-id/image-name', '.']

  # Push the container image to Container Registry
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args: ['push', 'gcr.io/project-id/image-name']

  # Deploy container image to Cloud Run
  - name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk'
    entrypoint: gcloud
    args: ['run', 'deploy', 'database-connection-test', '--image', 'gcr.io/project-id/image-name', '--region', 'europe-west4', '--vpc-connector', 'vpc-connector']

images:
  - gcr.io/project-id/image-name
```

Answer (score 1):

On Cloud Run instance, the Cloud SQL socket is opened only if you configure a database connection in your Service configuration

add those parameters in your Cloud Run deployment

```
'--add-cloudsql-instances', '<INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>'
```

In addition, accordingly to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-run#public-ip-default), you can't reach a Cloud SQL instance with private IP, only through public IP; and so you don't have to use a VPC connector.

OR, use a VPC connector and use the data private IP directly without sockets and Cloud Run database connection. (also documented)

Comment: Okay, from my approach I tried going the private IP route. Using your recommendation, I've tried using the private IP address in the datasource URL, scrapped off the other properties leaving the db username and password but it still didn't work. Unless I'm not doing it as it should be done